# Codecademy "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else"

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm doing the codecademy js course, and I'm at the part with rock paper scissors. When I save the code it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else". What did I do wrong?
This is my code:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
        {
            return ("rock wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return ("paper wins");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper");
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock")
        {
            return("paper wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return("scissors wins");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors")
    {
        if (choice2 === "paper");
        {
            return ("scissors wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return("rock wins");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove semicolon after if/else if/else

For e.g.

```
   else if (choice1 === "paper");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll see on the following line:

```
else if (choice1 === "paper");
```

, there's a semicolon where there shouldn't be.